# I am trying to use a selectedItem from a drop down menu in my SQL statement to populate a textbox in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

So far everything loads without error, and the SQL calls will be replaced with more secure stored procedures once everything is working. When I select a furnace from the drop down down menu, it should pass to the method and fill the textbox with the run number. But when I select anything, it only goes back to the first index 10A. I have also coded that index 0 should say "Select Furnace" but that is also not showing, only the first index. Is there any suggestions on how to grab a selected Index and populate a textbox from a SQL query?

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">
  <center>
   <table style="text-align:left">
    <tr>
     <td align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="FurnaceID" Text="JUMP TO FURNACE : " runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="FurnID" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true"
        onselectedindexchanged="FurnID_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="150px">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Furnace" Value = "0" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Behind The Code:

LoadList(); is called in the page_load event

```
   public void LoadList()
    {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Furnace]", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FurnaceDeckConnectionString"].ConnectionString));
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader Furns;
            Furns = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            FurnID.DataSource = Furns;

            FurnID.DataValueField = "Furnaceno";
            FurnID.DataTextField = "Furnaceno";
            FurnID.DataBind();

            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Dispose();

    }
```

When the index is changed this method is called:

```
protected void FurnID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            String selectedFurn = "";
            ListItem selectFurn = FurnID.Items.FindByText(selectedFurn);
            LoadFurnDetails(selectedFurn);
        }

    }

    public void LoadFurnDetails(String F)
    {
        String selectF = F;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Furnace Run Data Table] Where Furnace = 'selectF' and Completed = 0 ", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FurnaceDeckConnectionString"].ConnectionString));
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sqlDa.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblFurnId.Text = dt.Rows[0]["runno"].ToString();


        }

        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose(); 

    }
```

Comment: If you set your search variable _selectedFurn_ to an empty string and then use that variable as parameter to _FindByText_ it is really improbable that you find anything

Comment: btw: You should **never** and I really mean **NEVER** do such things without error handling (`try-catch-finally`) and `using()`. Your connection object should be in a using-block to make sure that it is freed and reusable in the connection pool. This will dispose it (and all bound objects!) automatically. If you run in an exception you would not even reach the `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` at the end!

Comment: I agree with you Shnugo, as stated above, this is a testing version of my code, the more secure version will be coded once functionality is present. But thank you.

Comment: @M.Beamon, this is something you should not even let away in a test prototype... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part

```
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        String selectedFurn = "";
        ListItem selectFurn = FurnID.Items.FindByText(selectedFurn);
        LoadFurnDetails(selectedFurn);
    }
```

... is defining a string "selectedFurn" as an empty string.
Then you try to find an Item by text with this empty string. I'd assume, that this Item doesn't exist... Anyway, you do not use the found ListItem, but just pass over the empty string...

You most propably are interested in the currently selected item and load details for this special item, aren't you? Try to find the `ListItem` with `.Selecteditem`rather than to pass the empty string as parameter in `LoadFurnDetails`...

The next problem is here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Furnace Run Data Table] Where Furnace = 'selectF' and Completed = 0 " ...
```

You think that you are passing in the variable "selectF" but you are searching for a hardcoded "selectF" actually... You must replace "selectF" by the actual content of the variable.

Again a no-go: You should **always** use parameters and do **not** concatenate a string command!

Answer (score 1):

@Schnugo, you gave the clues, and here is some code help if others are having this same problem. This solved it for me.

```
         if (IsPostBack)
        {

            String selectFurn = FurnID.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            SqlConnection m_sqlConnection;
            string m_connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FurnaceDeckConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (m_sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(m_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Load_Furn"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectFurn",  selectFurn);
                        cmd.Connection = m_sqlConnection;
                        m_sqlConnection.Open();
                        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (dr.HasRows)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `datareader` reads the data row by row and is used with a `while` statement to read the rows. You will have to use a [SqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) to fill a `dataset` that you can use as a datasource for the drop down menu. The default value should also be added to that dataset, otherwise it will not be shown after you set the datasource as you noticed.

Comment: I don't mind investigating and learning more about your answer. Could you provide any example of what that looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Load your data into a table, then use your table as the data.

Try this out:

```
public void LoadList()
{
    var table = new System.Data.DataTable("Furnaceno");
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FurnaceDeckConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Furnace]", conn))
        {
            table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    FurnID.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
    FurnID.DataValueField = "Furnaceno";
    FurnID.DataTextField = "Furnaceno";
    FurnID.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I think that the inner `using()` is not needed... The outer using of the connection should trigger a dispose cascade for all related objects... Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: I tried that, and nothing changed. I thank you so much for the effort and looking at it.

Comment: @Shnugo - a `using` statement is **never** needed.

Comment: @jp2code, Honestly? Well - one could say, that the GC will clean up everything when time comes. But - as you surely know - time may come late... Talking about database connections (free a connection in the connection pool!),  COM-wrappers and other consuming components I strongly disagree. The OP accepted my answer because I found the obvious mistakes he'd done. When I'd stumble over this thing, I'd think: Oh, why didn't I see this? and voted the other answer up instead of giving rather defiant comments. You used the `using` in your code, and you used it twice. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Shnugo, mostly it is just personal preference. I think it makes the code look cleaner and easier to tell what each object's primary job is. The "inner using statement" with the *SqlCommand* only serves to show how quickly we create, use, and dispose of that object. If it were called and created with traditional "in-line" code, it would still be out of scope after the "using statement" for the *SqlConnection* object.

Comment: @jp2code, without the `using` the `Dispose()` will not be called. The GC will dipose that object - at some time... If the data reading part is followed by a huge calculation this might be much later... If your objects are a circular referenced island, the GC will not dispose of that immediately but rather let the island hang around for a while... Especialliy with database connections a `using` is not just for "cleaner reading" but something really important.